# Make Django REST API accept a list

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a functionality where I need to be able to post a list consisting of properties to the API. A property has a `name`, `value` and `unit`. Now I have two questions:

1. How exactly should my list look for the API to accept it as a correct list from the get go? Should I parse the list as Objects? Or is a plain list fine?
2. I am using the Django REST framework and I have made the API using [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) tutorial (works perfectly). But how do I make Django accept multiple objects/a list? I have read that it is as simple as adding `many = True` to where you instantiate the serializer, which I do here:

(for some reason the code won't format unless I put text here)

```
class PropertyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  
    queryset = Property.objects.all()  
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer
```

So I tried doing `serializer = PropertySerializer(queryset, many=True)`, which broke the API view. So I think I have to create a new serializer and view just for this (am I right)? But how do I make sure that my API knows which one to use at the right time?

If anyone could clarify this that would be great, thanks.

Comment: are you trying to POST a list or GET a list?

Comment: @KevinL. I'm trying to post a list, getting works fine

Comment: so you are trying to post a list of objects `[obj1, obj2, ...]` and insert each object to the database?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to achieve here. Please remember, though, that part of my question was how to best pass the objects to the API. As of now, they aren't actually objects. But that shouldn't matter right now, since the API keeps returning the error that it expects a dictionary instead of a list. If I were to make it an array of objects it would return the same error.

Comment: well `viewset` doesn't accept list of objects, the create() method only accepts an individual object.

Comment: This much I understood as well. But my question is: say I create a new view, which doesn't use ViewSet, how would I tell my API that it should use that route when posting a list? Because I still want to keep the current ViewSet

Comment: sure you can keep the current viewset, just add your custom APIview to a different url not used by the viewset url e.g. if your viewset uses ` `r'^myModel/$'` then use `r'^myModel/createlist/$'` for the createlist custom APIview

Comment: If you literally wrote: `serializer = PropertySerializer(queryset, many=True) ` of course it breaks the view, because it should be serializer_class

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need to create the object, here is how I did it:

```
# Mixin that allows to create multiple objects from lists.
class CreateListModelMixin(object):
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ if an array is passed, set serializer to many """
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super(CreateListModelMixin, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then in the view that you would like to use it in just do:

```
class PropertyCreateView(CreateListModelMixin, generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```

And that's already it (make sure to put in the mixin as an argument BEFORE the view; like I did it).

Now the body of your postrequest would look like this:

```
{
  [
    {
      "name": "<some_name>"
      "value": "<some_value>"
      "unit": "<some_unit>"
    },
    {
      "name": "<some_name>"
      "value": "<some_value>"
      "unit": "<some_unit>"
    },
    {
      "name": "<some_name>"
      "value": "<some_value>"
      "unit": "<some_unit>"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The cool thing about it, this way you can also just post a single object like this:

```
{
  "name": "<some_name>"
  "value": "<some_value>"
  "unit": "<some_unit>"
}
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I fixed it according to the answer above, but your answer seems better practice to me and more complete. I'll see if I can't make this work too, and mark it as correct once I do :)

Comment: Thank you! I would appreciate the correct answer marking :)

Comment: Better late than never

Comment: How can I add a validation on single array items?

Answer (score 1):

`ModelViewSet` class provides a `create()` method which only allows you to create one object at a time. see [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

if you want to POST a list of objects and insert each object to the database, you would have to create a custom view. for e.g.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import MyModel

@api_view(['POST'])
def insert_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for obj in request.POST['list']: #assuming you are posting a 'list' of objects
            MyModel.objects.create(name=obj.name, value=obj.value, unit=obj.unit)
    return redirect('url of MyObject List View')
```

to use your custom APIview alongside the viewset, just add your custom APIview to a different url not used by the viewset url e.g. if your viewset uses `r'^myModel/$'` then use `r'^myModel/insert_list/$'` for the createlist custom APIview

Comment: After finetuning this a bit it worked, thanks! Two quick questions though, I couldn't access my list via the `request.POST['list']` you used. I had to use `request.data`. Should I fix this, or is it okay? And the other question, I noticed some other answers used serializers, is there any disadvantage in this case not to?

Comment: That’s fine I was just using ‘list’ for illustrative purpose

Comment: The other answer looks good too it’s the CBV equivalent of my solution.

Comment: Cant bulk create handle this?